# How to stub chained functions using sinon in TypeORM

Tags: sinon, typeorm

I'm currently using TypeORM and Sinonjs in my project. But I'm not sure how to write the unit test in the right way. Especially how to stub a chained function call, like this

```js
  async find(id: number): Promise<User> {
    const user = await this.connection
      .getRepository(User)
      .createQueryBuilder("user")
      .where("user.id = :id", { id: id })
      .getOne();
    return user;
  }
```

My test file

```js
it('should return a data from db', async () => {
  let user = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'my name'
  };

  const getOne = Sinon.stub().resolves(user);
  const where = Sinon.stub().callsArg(0);
  const createQueryBuilder = Sinon.stub().callsArg(0);
  const connection = {
    getRepository: Sinon.stub()
  };

  connection.getRepository.withArgs(User).returns(createQueryBuilder);
  createQueryBuilder.withArgs('user').returns(where);
  where.withArgs('user.id = :id', { id: user.id }).returns(getOne);
});
```

I always got this error

> TypeError: this.connection.getRepository(...).createQueryBuilder is not a function

Any advice is welcome! 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `sinon.stub(obj, 'method').returnsThis()` to

> Causes the stub to return its this value.

E.g.

`index.ts`:

```js
type User = any;

export const model = {
  connection: {
    getRepository(model) {
      return this;
    },
    createQueryBuilder(model) {
      return this;
    },
    where(query, bindings) {
      return this;
    },
    getOne() {
      console.log('get one');
    }
  },
  async find(id: number): Promise<User> {
    const user = await this.connection
      .getRepository('User')
      .createQueryBuilder('user')
      .where('user.id = :id', { id: id })
      .getOne();
    return user;
  }
};
```

`index.spec.ts`:

```js
import { model } from './';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import { expect } from 'chai';

describe('model', () => {
  describe('#find', () => {
    afterEach(() => {
      sinon.restore();
    });
    it('should find user', async () => {
      let mUser = {
        id: 1,
        name: 'my name'
      };

      const getRepository = sinon.stub(model.connection, 'getRepository').returnsThis();
      const createQueryBuilder = sinon.stub(model.connection, 'createQueryBuilder').returnsThis();
      const where = sinon.stub(model.connection, 'where').returnsThis();
      const getOne = sinon.stub(model.connection, 'getOne').resolves(mUser);

      const user = await model.find(1);
      expect(user).to.be.eql(mUser);
      expect(getRepository.calledWith('User')).to.be.true;
      expect(createQueryBuilder.calledWith('user')).to.be.true;
      expect(where.calledWith('user.id = :id', { id: 1 })).to.be.true;
      expect(getOne.calledOnce).to.be.true;
    });
  });
});
```

Unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
 model
    #find
      ✓ should find user


  1 passing (13ms)

---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File           |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files      |    86.21 |      100 |    55.56 |    84.62 |                   |
 index.spec.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts      |       50 |      100 |       20 |    42.86 |         6,9,12,15 |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/57843415